# Well-defined formal power series

Tags: combinatorics, power-series, formal-power-series

I am working on the following problem:

Assume we are working in a formal power series ring $R[[x]]$ over a ring $R$ containing $\mathbb{Q}$. Define $\exp(x)$ and $\log(1 + x)$ by their usual Taylor series. Given $F(x), G(x) \in R[[x]]$ such that $F(0) = 1$, show that there is a well-defined formal power series
\begin{equation}
F(x)^{G(x)} \overset{def}{=} \exp(G(x) \log F(x)).
\end{equation}
What I think is the following: Given that $H(x) = G(x)\log F(x)$ makes sense as a formal power series (multiplication of formal power series is always valid), so I just need to prove that the composition of $H(x)$ and $\exp(x)$, as formal power series, makes sense, i.e. $H(0) = 0$. Am I right or am I missing something else?

Comment: Doesnt that just follow from $\log 1=0$ ?

Comment: If the expression makes sense in the context of $R[[x]]$, then yes, but I believe we need to prove this first.

Answer (score 0):

You may have solved the problem here but anyway, it might be useful. I think you are missing a point here.

In order to be able to define $F(x)^{G(x)}$, what you do is correct. Indeed you need $H(0)=0$. But you don't really have to prove anything. Indeed :

$$\log(F(x))=\log(1+(F(x)-1))$$

Means that you are composing $\log(1+x)$ with $F(x)-1$ which is correct because $(F(x)-1)(0)=1-1=0$ (Maybe that is what you should have written). Afterward, you just have to use the following general fact: provided that $U(V(x))$ makes sense (i.e. $V(0)=0$), the $0$-th term of $U(V(x))$ is the same as $U(0)$ which can easily be seen when you define the composition.